# GPG decryption challenge. No passphrase available - Unknown sender / GPG

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I am doing an online challenge and I am wondering how someone would go about getting the data that is encrypted?

any advice would be great. the website is defendtheweb.net

I have put the full encryption below:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----  
owEBfQKC/ZANAwAIAUi/Y1ergOteAaweYg1wZ3AxaW5wdXQudHh0XSYJ3khlbGxv  
IHdvcmxkiQJLBAABCAA1FiEE6DCERSe70kQIH/X5SL9jV6uA614FAl0mCd4XHGFp  
ZGVuQGRlZmVuZHRoZXdlYi5uZXQACgkQSL9jV6uA6150GRAAsMaWuzODcLaGEP62  
7a/JaGUB/nKAFhDEo7J9JEihn92q9efNPjEMH97WJl4GU25cUZLyrtp4cDl5mZ0T  
CiguNISviQLHKTz6KBgxoxEi5QCgh0uygfVCdJOL+Gah+EWqSZ1ACSrt+ilMJRna  
rppcNPvwUUP3fw/QcqcoHWIh4Y4Nij0Q3+ywGNgi+JxBWUnWI5RJdSY579dCNOgD  
RJW4FcWHNovKuAgs0pNBU+TX07qJpdH9Kmru5D+QDKFTVBIgDxs2EDHa/tMRgG6C  
MNVnEW4MsAcwqOaU6M/HyzQdy27nRJZjYFImM5si8JXk8whWUAJU5EOQuQsO62X8  
MsFqyIuSWMq3SY0tCXrWZwcT7t3zR9DyxZQRXEjmcp6XwnjqZKL2C8H4r3knu4vm  
JaofblxYHuMWDjzMPD7KGUyuhHBDWSBGBs3njGgplzUWcYaNtegmj2x/a3TjSznF  
bHZPA6VHQLzlEnSZe243Wx5PGVuYOxqkBKe9wD48xJXWnblu7UE73WKy5r8q2Qma  
q9l/TZfs3OZ23HNK1aPJ7Aii3FD4KF31KrwbOq54oO/8J15Vygz/S0XJmE4WdXJD  
gMnSRdNNyeUlOQmgeNx8NW0wRhW0bQclHSAUKyw6p5WbzYB8KSnLfDBIx2p8FfJb  
DK8y2toYISJVK3qK+CEjl3ntntE=  
=He9M  
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Comment: The challenge is for *you*. Good luck ;-)

Comment: Pahaha Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gpg` with `-d` option.

From [`gpg`'s manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/gpg.1.html):

> **--decrypt**
>       **-d**  Decrypt  the  file given on the command line (or STDIN if no file is specified) and
>           write it to STDOUT (or the file specified with --output). If the decrypted file  is
>           signed,  the  signature  is  also  verified.  This command differs from the default
>           operation, as it never writes to the filename which is included in the file and  it
>           rejects files that don't begin with an encrypted message.

To decrypt the message, create a text file and paste the message including `-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----` and `-----END PGP MESSAGE-----`. After creating file, open a terminal and run,

```
gpg -d filename
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to figure this out with your help, much appreciated. By any chance you wouldn't know anything about stenography would you lol

Comment: hey kulfy,

Can i ask how do you add the public key I got the below message?

gpg: Can't check signature: No public key